# Configure Runtime for Projects - Missing projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-java

I am attempting to switch from IntelliJ to VsCode for developing and debugging an application that has a bunch of microservices that are organized in multiple projects, using various versions of Java and Gradle.  I am able to open them all in VsCode and set the Java version for most of them via the "Configure Runtime for Projects" tab that I open via the Explorer "Java Projects" menu item.

My problem is that a couple of projects don't show up on the "Configure Runtime for Projects" tab, so I can't specify their Java Version. These projects are listed under "Java Projects", but when I expand their entries, I see nothing -- unlike the other projects.

What's different about the projects that don't show up on "Configure Runtime for Projects" is that they use Gradle 2.9 (!).  (Yeah, I know these should be updated.  That's somewhere on the backlog.)

How can I set the Java version for these 2 projects?

Comment: I should add that these are Spring Boot projects, using Spring Boot 1.3.3 (!).  They show up in the Spring Extension, but when I launch them from there, they use Java 11. That's why I need to configure these to use Java 8.

Comment: I went looking for the file where the "Configure Java Runtime" information is stored, hoping that I could add the 2 missing projects manually -- but I can't find it.  I looked in my user, project, and workspace settings .json files, and all over the ~/Library/Application Support/Code folder.

So where is this information stored?

Comment: I expected the target jdk to be specified in the launch configuration.  I discovered (via Intellisense) a configuration attribute named "javaExec" that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.  I tried setting "javaExec" to the folder that contains the correct jdk (i.e. "~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_392/Contents/Home/bin") but all that gets me is "<className> doesn't exist in the workspace" -- which is not true.

Comment: I fixed the "<className> doesn't exist in the workspace" by adding the "projectName" attribute. But now it just says "The project is not a valid java project."

Comment: I rebooted my machine, and now none of my Java 1.8 projects show up on the "Configure Runtime for Projects" tab -- even one that was there yesterday. I've tried:
* Explicitly configuring the JRE's in my workspace settings file
* Adding source/targetCompatibility in the build.gradle file

This is driving me back to IntelliJ.